# How to use SceneBuilder's DarkTheme in my application

Tags: java, css, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

**Firstly**, is it legal to use the dark theme of `JavaFX`'s SceneBuilder 2 in my application? Since it is open source now here: [SceneBuilder/css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u/rt/file/5fc0ddb42776/apps/scenebuilder/SceneBuilderApp/src/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app/css/)
**Secondly**, how to do this if legal? Or just for training purposes if not legal?
I tried to download the `ThemeDark.css` file from the link above and add it to my fxml file, but i see no change applied.

**Any ideas ?**
**Edit (what I did):**

1. I have downloaded the .css file and pasted it in package css.
2. Then I added these lines in my .fxml file (with the <> symbols but I removed them in this question as they hid the text if present) :
   stylesheets
     URL value="@/css/ThemeDark.css"
   /stylesheets
3. See below resulting screenshot: (themeDark not applied)

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you are using SceneBuilder you can add a global css sheet to it and be happy with the new look.
Alternative, if you want to set it within your code you can use

```
scene.getStylesheets().clear();
scene.getStylesheets().add("path/stylesheet.css"); // Modify to your path
```

to add a style-sheet. Notice that you should put your style-sheet in a resource folder in your application, just to keep everything cleaned up.

Comment: I asking specifically for the css style used by SceneBuilder (the Dark Theme) not in general how to use any css.

Comment: @Dimitris Interesting tough that you say "how to do this" and "add it to my fxml file, but i see no change applied", which means you downloaded the theme but failed to add it to your application. For exactly that problem, i offered a solution. If this is not the right appempt, please specify your question and offer more details